# Tamil fonts mess up HTML element's alignment and design

Tags: html, css, tamil

Why the Tamil words are not aligning correctly as English words and why its change the default html element behavior?

For example I include the code sample below for your clarification and it is better to open it with firefox because it will clearly show the difference between the select boxes.

```html
<body>
  <select>
    <option>June</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option>ஜூன்</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

It may be a small issue, but don't have a clear idea about this behavior.

I'll be so glad if someone explain me why this is happening and what should i do to solve this..?

screen-shot when open this in firefox.
[image]

Comment: I dont see any difference between them. Could you share a screenshot of the problem ?

Comment: If you open this in firefox you can see the issue.. I posted the screen shot how its look like in firefox. You can find that the tamil font slightly went down in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English fonts are generated by ASCII codes and Tamil,kanada,malayalam etc are generated by the help of Unicode so it may take some extra spacing... using the css You can control the size of that dropbox.

Comment: Actually I use one combo box with some css on it. I only change the data inside the combo box. So I cant change the css of the combo box and i don't want to load different css according to the data-set language. Is there any way to remove the extra space that you mentioned..?

Answer (score 0):

It must take some extra space vertically because of the nature of the fonts.
I would recommend using a general css to equalize the height of all dropdowns.

```
select{
    height:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
select.extraPadding{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>

<select class="extraPadding">
   <option>June</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't prefer to adjust the combo box. I am trying to correctly fit the Tamil word in the combo box.

Comment: Maybe change the font-size?